# Issue when call html instead of an anchor Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, uinavigationbar

I created the company page that I work on, and I'm having a problem when I click the menu and call a new page instead of scrolling the page to anchor.

I have researched here and on several other forums, but the problem I am having is when I call an html page instead of calling the id #xpto.

```js
scrollChange: function() {
  var windowTop = this.$win.scrollTop();
  var position = this.getSection(windowTop);
  var $parent;

  //If the position is set
  if(position !== null) {
    $parent = this.$elem.find('a[href$="#' + position + '"]').parent();

 //If it's not already the current section
 if(!$parent.hasClass(this.config.currentClass)) {
   //Change the highlighted nav item
      this.adjustNav(this, $parent);

   //If there is a scrollChange callback
   if(this.config.scrollChange) {
     this.config.scrollChange($parent);
   }
 }
  }
},

scrollTo: function(target, callback) {
  var offset = $(target).offset().top;

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, this.config.scrollSpeed, this.config.easing, callback);
},

unbindInterval: function() {
  clearInterval(this.t);
    this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
  }
};
```

```html
<!-- main nav -->
<nav class="collapse navigation navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
  <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
    <li><a href="produtos.html">Produtos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#clientes">Clientes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#produtos">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- /main nav -->
```

When I call, for example, the Services link, I realize that there is a bug in the presentation of the page (it is very subtle, almost imperceptible). I checked the code and saw that there really is the issue, but I do not know yet I was able to correct for the behavior to be the same (either html or anchor)

[image]

Comment: it looks like `$(target)` is failing in `scrollTo`. It's hard to know why without seeing more code. What is `target` in this instance?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You haven't shown where your scrollTo method is even used

Comment: like I said, the target that show problem is html target. If I click on <a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a> the target is a html page and not an anchor to the same index page.